# TCP/IP iOS client

Tags: ios, wifi, tcp

My question is: is there any **TCP/IP** framework in iOS SDK?

What I want to do is to create a simple client that receives some data sent by a PC over a Wifi.
Is this possible without using a higher level protocol?

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

Comment: Apple has a nice doc on Networking, you should read it. Search on network on the apple dev site.